# Liferay Service not getting deployed to Axis

Tags: liferay, portlet, portal

I am creating a liferay service, I generated a lot of classes. When i try to build-service using Liferay ServiceBUilder, it shows in console that My service is build succesfully

```
[Console output redirected to file:/home/rajeshp/Desktop/LiferayDeveloperStudio/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/com.liferay.ide.eclipse.sdk/sdk.log]
Buildfile: /home/rajeshp/Desktop/LiferayDeveloperStudio/workspace/trunk/portlets/rosetta-services-portlet/build.xml
build-service:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /home/rajeshp/Desktop/LiferayDeveloperStudio/workspace/trunk/portlets/rosetta-services-portlet/docroot/WEB-INF/classes
     [echo] Loading jar:file:/home/rajeshp/Desktop/LiferayDeveloperStudio/liferay-portal-6.0-ee-sp2/tomcat-6.0.32/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties
     [echo] 16:27:07,649 INFO  [EasyConf:122] Refreshed the configuration of all components
     [echo] 16:27:08,250 INFO  [ConfigurationLoader:56] Properties for jar:file:/home/rajeshp/Desktop/LiferayDeveloperStudio/liferay-portal-6.0-ee-sp2/tomcat-6.0.32/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal loaded from [jar:file:/home/rajeshp/Desktop/LiferayDeveloperStudio/liferay-portal-6.0-ee-sp2/tomcat-6.0.32/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/com/liferay/portal/tools/dependencies/portal-tools.properties, jar:file:/home/rajeshp/Desktop/LiferayDeveloperStudio/liferay-portal-6.0-ee-sp2/tomcat-6.0.32/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal.properties]
     [echo] Loading jar:file:/home/rajeshp/Desktop/LiferayDeveloperStudio/liferay-portal-6.0-ee-sp2/tomcat-6.0.32/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal.properties
     [echo] Loading jar:file:/home/rajeshp/Desktop/LiferayDeveloperStudio/liferay-portal-6.0-ee-sp2/tomcat-6.0.32/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/com/liferay/portal/tools/dependencies/portal-tools.properties
     [echo] 16:27:11,976 INFO  [PortalImpl:295] Global lib directory /home/rajeshp/Desktop/LiferayDeveloperStudio/liferay-portal-6.0-ee-sp2/tomcat-6.0.32/lib/ext/
     [echo] 16:27:11,978 INFO  [PortalImpl:315] Portal lib directory /home/rajeshp/Desktop/LiferayDeveloperStudio/liferay-portal-6.0-ee-sp2/tomcat-6.0.32/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/
     [echo] Building ECData
     [echo] Building WebArticleHelper
   [delete] Deleting: /home/rajeshp/Desktop/LiferayDeveloperStudio/workspace/trunk/portlets/rosetta-services-portlet/ServiceBuilder.temp
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/rajeshp/Desktop/LiferayDeveloperStudio/workspace/trunk/portlets/rosetta-services-portlet/docroot/WEB-INF/service-classes
compile-java:
    [javac] Compiling 18 source files to /home/rajeshp/Desktop/LiferayDeveloperStudio/workspace/trunk/portlets/rosetta-services-portlet/docroot/WEB-INF/service-classes
      [zip] Building zip: /home/rajeshp/Desktop/LiferayDeveloperStudio/workspace/trunk/portlets/rosetta-services-portlet/docroot/WEB-INF/lib/rosetta-services-portlet-service.jar
   [delete] Deleting directory /home/rajeshp/Desktop/LiferayDeveloperStudio/workspace/trunk/portlets/rosetta-services-portlet/docroot/WEB-INF/service-classes
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 16 seconds
```

But I cant see the service deployed in Liferay Developer studio
[image]

Also, when i open http://localhost:8080/tunnel-web/axis

I cant find my service there,

the services-portlet is not giving any error while compiling, deploying, building-services, to add to more frustration, the same services-portlet and services are getting deployed in my collegeue's machine.

Can anybody figure out what the problem is? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Once you run build-services you need to run build-wsdd ant task (or click "build wsdd" in the service.xml editor in the IDE).  Also to try to test this you have to right-click the portlet project that is shown in the servers view and select "test web services".  Or if you want to see the url directly you should use:

http://localhost:8080/rosetta-services-portlet/tunnel-web/axis

Answer (score 0):

I think the link is : http://localhost:8080/rosetta-services-portlet/axis
........